How can I determine whether a Word document has a password?
I am trying to read word documents using Python. However, I am stuck in places where the document is password protected, as I do not have the password for the file(s).
How can I detect if the file has password, so can I ignore such files from opening?
Currently, the below code opens a dialog/prompt window in MS-Word to enter the password and keeps waiting for a response.
word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open(r"D:\appointment\PasswordProtectedDoc.doc")


Will they be ".doc" files or actually ".docx" files?

files with .doc extension

Well I figured out the answer myself. Passed a wrong password as a parameter and it raised an exception saying Invalid/Incorrect password which I can handle it in a try except block. Little strange but works well.
word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
word.Visible = False
try:
    doc = word.Documents.Open(r"D:\appointment\PasswordProtectedDoc.doc",PasswordDocument='ddd')
    doc.Activate ()
except:
    print(f"Failed to open")
finally:
    word.Quit()

